# AJAX send value of button to ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to send the value button to another page with AJAX.

This is the ajax script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
      var userId = $(this).val()
      var dataString = "docName="+userId; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
        type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
        url: "parse_trainingen.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
        data: dataString, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
        success: function(result){ /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
          $("#resultaat").html(result); /* THE RETURNED DATA WILL BE SHOWN IN THIS DIV */
         alert('OK');
        }
      
      });
}
  });
</script>
```

And this is the button (echoëd in PHP)

```
<button type="button" class="mpf_btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-'.$color.' btn-block" 
value="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</button>
```

When i click the button, nothing happends. What's going wrong?

Comment: Add an `error` handler to your AJAX call and see what it will return. Also, check your developer toolbar network tab to see if the AJAX call is even triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having trouble with code I will suggest you use function  to collecting data from onclick event like this.

```
function getdata(value){
 //check your value through console log
  console.log(value);

 }
```

Then you use onclick to send the data

```
<button onclick="getdata(this.value)" value="">click</button>
```

This should send data to the function

Comment: Thank you, i got this: "SyntaxError: Expected ')' (Edge)
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list (Firefox)"

So this was the solution: added ) after } on the second } from below.